# Render partial from Helper in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I have read a lot of guides but I can not understand why this my method does not work:

```
module StudentsHelper
    def get_training_projects
        @training_projects_student = TrainingProject.where(student_id: @student.id)
        @training_projects_student.count
    end

    def get_training_courses
        @training_course_student = TrainingCourse.joins(:courses_students).where(courses_students: { student_id: @student.id })
        @training_course_student.count
    end

    def storico_studente
        n = get_training_courses + get_training_projects
        i_projects = 0
        i_courses = 0
        until i_courses + i_projects < n
            if @training_course_student[i_courses].data_inizio < @training_projects_student[i_projects].data_inizio
                render partial: "training_course", collection:@training_course_student[i_cousers]
                i_courses += 1
            else
            render partial: "training_project", collection: @training_course_student[i_projects]
            i_projects += 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The "_training_project.html.erb" and "_training_course.html.erb" files are in the folder students.

**Update:**

In the code above, the loop was wrong, never enters.

```
  def storico_studente
        n_training_courses = get_training_courses
        n_training_projects = get_training_projects
        n = n_training_courses + n_training_projects 
        i_projects = 0
        i_courses = 0
        while i_courses + i_projects < n

            if @training_course_student[i_courses].nil?
                render partial: 'students/training_project', collection: @training_course_student[i_projects]
                i_projects += 1 if i_projects < n_training_projects

            elsif @training_projects_student[i_projects].nil?
                render partial: 'students/training_course', collection: @training_course_student[i_courses]
                i_courses += 1 if i_courses < n_training_courses

            elsif @training_course_student[i_courses].data_inizio < @training_projects_student[i_projects].data_inizio
                render partial: 'students/training_course', collection: @training_course_student[i_courses]
                i_courses += 1 if i_courses < n_training_courses
            else
                render partial: 'students/training_project', collection: @training_course_student[i_projects]
                i_projects += 1 if i_projects < n_training_projects
            end

        end

    end
```

now the loop work fine, I can see the correct call in the logs:

```
  Rendered students/_training_course.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered students/_training_project.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered students/_training_course.html.erb (0.0ms)
```

the files contain only (for the moment)

```
<div>ptoject</div>
```

end

```
<div>course</div>
```

this explain the load time (0.0ms)

But it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `until` loop should be a `while` loop. Since `i_projects` and `i_courses` are both initialized to zero and `n` will always be greater than or equal to zero, your loop only executes when `n` is zero.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that your helper method isn't returning the rendered partials. It is rendering them, as confirmed by your logs, but the result never gets returned. I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but here is a solution:

```
def storico_studente
  n_training_courses = get_training_courses
  n_training_projects = get_training_projects
  n = n_training_courses + n_training_projects 
  i_projects = 0
  i_courses = 0

  partials = []

  while i_courses + i_projects < n
    if @training_course_student[i_courses].nil?
      partials << render(partial: 'students/training_project', collection: @training_course_student[i_projects])
      i_projects += 1 if i_projects < n_training_projects
    elsif @training_projects_student[i_projects].nil?
      partials << render(partial: 'students/training_course', collection: @training_course_student[i_courses])
      i_courses += 1 if i_courses < n_training_courses
    elsif @training_course_student[i_courses].data_inizio < @training_projects_student[i_projects].data_inizio
      partials << render(partial: 'students/training_course', collection: @training_course_student[i_courses])
      i_courses += 1 if i_courses < n_training_courses
    else
      partials << render(partial: 'students/training_project', collection: @training_course_student[i_projects])
      i_projects += 1 if i_projects < n_training_projects
    end
  end

  safe_join partials
end
```

Comment: oops, this is embarrassing! Thanks, I've updated the post, because despite the call in the log is done, still does not work...

Comment: can I call the method in this way:  <%= storico_studente%>?

Comment: Yeah, just put that in your view.

Comment: nothing's changed...  I try to `puts "#{partials}"`, the result is: [nil, nil, nil]

Comment: I think you should be using `object: ...` as opposed to `collection: ...`.